# How to Use MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
MKLocalSearchCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error)
{ ... };
```

How do i convert this completion handler in swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code that demonstrates:

```
let localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurants"

let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
    print(localSearchResponse)
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark my answer as correct so that others can benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code that is compatible with Swift3:

```
let localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "restaurants"

let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in
    print(localSearchResponse ?? "no results")
}
```